# How to resolve "Reference to undefined variable rcp_xulrunner" error on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, lotus-notes, expeditor

I'm trying to create a Notes Client plugin (using Lotus Expeditor Toolkit 6.2.2).

I have been following the video tutorials from this website - https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/video_creating_your_fist_eclipse_plugin_for_lotus_notes.

Currently, I'm stuck on step #1.

1. I have downloaded and installed Eclipse Ganymede 3.4.2 (Eclipse for RCP/Plug-in Developers)
2. Installed Lotus Expeditor Toolkit 6.2.2 in the Eclipse Ganymede
3. **This is where the issue is coming up** - In Run Configurations, I added a new Client Services and named it as "Notes" as seen in the video tutorial and then clicked Apply. When I try to click run, an error message is displayed:

[image: error message]

Any insights on how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by doing the following:

1. Downloaded xulrunner 1.9 and installed in this directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla XULRunner\1.9
2. Edited the VM arguments in Run configurations from:

"-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=${rcp_xulrunner}/xulrunner"

to

"-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla XULRunner\1.9"